# How to put sum by model in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'model':['a','a','a','b', 'b','c','c','d','d','d'],
   'qty':[1,2,1,3,1,5, 2,3,4,5]})
```

[image]

There is one dataframe with a model and qty as columns.

I want to add the summer column at the end like below pic

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? It seems to me that a `groupby` or `transform` could sole your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform()` to calculate the sum, then `duplicated` to identify the first rows:

```
df.loc[~df['model'].duplicated(), 'sum'] = df.groupby('model')['qty'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
  model  qty   sum
0     a    1   4.0
1     a    2   NaN
2     a    1   NaN
3     b    3   4.0
4     b    1   NaN
5     c    5   7.0
6     c    2   NaN
7     d    3  12.0
8     d    4   NaN
9     d    5   NaN
```

If you want the empty string instead of `NaN` (not recommended), you can use `np.where`:

```
df['sum'] = np.where(df['model'].duplicated(), '', df.groupby('model')['qty'].transform('sum'))
```

Output:

```
  model  qty sum
0     a    1   4
1     a    2    
2     a    1    
3     b    3   4
4     b    1    
5     c    5   7
6     c    2    
7     d    3  12
8     d    4    
9     d    5
```